# Pass image ArrayBuffer to Azure Face SDK detectWithStream()

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk

I am trying to write a NodeJS app that grabs a image from private URL using Axios and passes it to the Azure Face SDK (documentation) to detect faces in the image and get attributes of those faces - in this case, emotions and head pose.

I have gotten a modified version of the quickstart example code here working, which makes a call to the detectWithUrl() method. However, the image that I have in my code is a ArrayBuffer, so I thought I would try calling detectWithStream() instead. The documentation for this method says it needs to be passed something of type msRest.HttpRequestBody - I found some documentation for this type, which looks like it wants to be a **Blob, string, ArrayBuffer, or ArrayBufferView**. The problem is, I don't really understand what those are or how I might get from a arraybuffer image to an HttpRequestBody of that type. I have worked with HTTP requests before, but I don't quite understand why one is being passed to this method, or how to make it.

```
        const rqs = {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            url: `${fileUrl}`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `image/jpeg`,
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            },
            httpsAgent: agent
        };

        axios.request(rqs)
            .then((ret) => {
                // ret.data is a ArrayBuffer type;

                let detected_faces = client.face.detectWithStream(ret.data, {
                   returnFaceAttributes: ["Accessories", "Age", "Blur", "Emotion", "Exposure", "FacialHair", "Glasses", "Hair", "HeadPose", "Makeup", "Noise", "Occlusion", "Smile", "QualityForRecognition"],
                   detectionModel: "detection_01",
                   recognitionModel: "recognition_03"
               })
               .then(ok => {
                   console.log(ok);
                   console.log("face(s) detected from image.");
                   console.log("Face attributes for face(s):");
               })
               .catch(err => {
                   console.error(err.message);
               });
               console.log('ok');
               resolve(ret.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('nok');
                console.error(err.message);
                reject(false)
            });
```

And I had receive a message error ***Only absolute URLs are supported***

Answer (score 0):

1. Only absolute URLs are supported -
   a. it may be due to passing relative URL to Axios in line 3, try checking the fileUrl.
   b. check the face SDK is provided with the proper endpoint

   relative URL - "./a/b"
   absolute URL - "https://www.x.com/a/b"
2. how I might get from an array buffer image?
   Array buffer is not needed. Looking at face SDK code [Ref](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/a67bdbda5bd4384cbbee8cf6d17d77995c47531c/sdk/cognitiveservices/cognitiveservices-face/src/operations/face.ts#L349) ([hope this is right sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cognitiveservices-face)), we just need streams.
   we can get this by changing the responseType value to stream

   responseType: 'arraybuffer', // current
   responseType: 'stream', // updated - we can update it in rqs and reponse will be stream and you can pass res.data to detectWithStream function

***-------------------------------------Hope the code works----------------------------------------***

**Recommendation:**
You are creating a callback hell by using nested .then chains [what is call back hell](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-callback-hell-in-node-js/).
Try using async/await syntax to achieve the same functionality in a simplified way - [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Regards,
Muhamed